# Delay after re-establishing a bonded link

Tags: port, bonding

I have a CentOS 6 server with two bonded ethernet ports. Both ports are connected to a switch which I then connect to a laptop.

If I flood-ping the laptop and disconnect one of the bonded ports, some packets (~20) are lost before things stabilise. This happens in a fraction of a second. However, if I then plug the cable back in, I drop packets for 30 seconds before things go back to normal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Bonded how ? Are you using LACP between the server and the switch ?

If not, the devices will have to do normal ARP discovery to re-establish the bonded link; this may well take that long.

Comment: It's currently using mode 0 / round-robin. I'll try tinkering with different modes if it's more likely to be a server thing than a switch thing. The switch is a Dell PowerConnect, is there likely to be any tweaks needed for that or should it just work?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `balance-alb`, Debian 6.0 and ZyXEL ES-2024A switches. Meaning: way too many variables. If you are using a switch-agnostic approach like `balance-alb`, can you try using `balance-tlb`?

That was enough for my purposes, so I stopped my debugging at that point. If not, we'll need MOAR details, as @adaptr said.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your switch ports are not configured with spanning-tree portfast. When your server port recovers it will immediately be placed back in the bond but the switch will need to go through 2 x forward delay (30s) before it will resuming forwarding on that port.